# FileUpload UX plugin for Boundless?

Tags: boundless-suite, ext-js

I am busy building a web map app using boundless SDK.
I am trying to implement a file up-loader, however, the majority of examples use
`new Ext.ux.form.FileUploadField`
When I try to use it in my project it says that the xtype is not recognised.

I am currently using this:

    `xtype : 'textfield',
    inputType:'file',`

But I find it cumbersome, ugly and have to add allot of extra code to make sure validation fires when file is selected etc...

How can I make the FileUpload UX plugin part of my project?

I am quite new to the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look at how this is done in GeoExplorer: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/tree/master/geoexplorer/app/static/script/ux

1) Add the Ext JS user extension to scripts/ux
2) Add it your buildjs.cfg file: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/geoexplorer/buildjs.cfg

It should then get included in the build of your application if you add a @require for it in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at it. So far it looks like what I am looking for.

Comment: I was as  bit confused about the implementation of the solution, but got it working after a bit of reading and figuring out. Thank you.

Comment: Just one last remark, you would not by any chance have the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559284/extjs-3-4-file-upload-not-processing-error-message-from-php). It is with regard to getting the response from PHP after file has been processed on server